# Delphi 7 - Decode base 64 string to a file

Tags: delphi, base64, delphi-7, decode

I am trying to find a way to decode base64 string and then save it to a file using Delphi 7 (this specific Delphi version).

The base64 string it-self is a PDF file, encoded to base64 as part of HL7 message. Almost all examples that I found were not compatible with Delphi 7.

Anyone can help?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Remy Lebeau to use TidDecoderMIME.
Is this the correct way to decode and save to binary file?

`var
    MStream:TMemoryStream;
    Decoder:TIdDecoderMIME;
    Base64: string;
begin
    Decoder := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
    MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Base64 := 'abcd1234';
    Decoder.DecodeToStream(Base64,MStream);
    MStream.SaveToFile('example.pdf');
    FreeAndNil(Decoder);
    FreeAndNil(MStream);
end;`

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: EncdDecd unit has a function to decode directly to a stream. DecodeStream. Send in a string stream with the encoded base64, and a file stream.

Comment: Just test it to see if it is the correct way! And maybe use some try..finally blocks.

Comment: I tested against web decoder http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp, and the result is different. The web decoder produced correct output file. While the Delphi code above produced wrong output file, bigger file size. Does the MemoryStream save differently?

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake on my routine. Actually, the above code works! On Delphi 7 :)

Comment: Are you using Indy for anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi ships with Indy, which has a `TIdDecoderMIME` class for decoding base64 strings.

Comment: I am not familiar with TIdDecoderMIME. Would the updated code example be the correct way?

Comment: @ewlung: For Indy 9, yes. For Indy 10, the decoder interface is different, but there is a `class` procedure that wraps everything into a single statement: `TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Base64, MStream);`. In either version, you can optionally replace the `TMemoryStream` with a `TFileStream` since you want to save the decoded data to a file.